# Difficulty accessing specific data in axios GET request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, axios

I'm using the CryptoCompare API (https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#-api-data-coinlist-) and I'm having difficulty accessing specific coin information on search. Instead, I'm returned the whole list of coins rather than the one I searched. I'm guessing it's a problem within my then statement, but I'm not sure. Here's the code I have so far-- the problem area is in searchImage

```html
class SearchForm extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            currentSearch: "",
            priceResults: [],
            cryImage: [],
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.cryPrice = this.cryPrice.bind(this);
    }

    cryPrice(param){
        axios.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=${param}&tsyms=CAD`)
            .then(res => {
                const cryptos = res.data;
                console.log(cryptos);
                this.setState({
                    priceResults: cryptos
                })
            })
        }

    searchImage(param){
        axios.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist`, {
            params: {
                name: `${param}`,
            }
        }).then(res => {
            const cryImage = res.data;
            console.log(cryImage);
            this.setState({
                cryImage 
            })
        })
    }

   
    handleChange(e){
        const currentSearchValue = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            currentSearch: currentSearchValue
        })
        console.log(currentSearchValue);
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.cryPrice(this.state.currentSearch);
        this.searchImage(this.state.currentSearch);
        this.setState({
            currentSearch: ""
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It says in the docs (from my understanding) that this get request takes no params.

> **CoinList**
>
> Get general info for all the coins available on the website.
>
> **URL Parameters**
>
> None

So when you send the request you will always get all of the coins. Now what you can do is filter the only one you are interested in through the response. This means that in the body of the function you are using in your `.then` you can simply read the info about the coin given through `param`.